# Unit test - Moq abstract class with SetOwinContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to `Moq` to test `abstract class method`.

```
var mock = new Mock<BaseStudentController>();
mock.CallBase = true;
var ta = mock.Object;
var result = await ta.ActivateStudent"User1@test.com", true);
```

This successfully mocks the base class, and it hits the method in my abstract class.

**Problem:**

However, my abstract class is also expecting `Request.GetOwinContext`. I am not sure how i can moq it along with my above request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up `ControllerContext` before calling `ActivateStudent`

```
ta.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext { Request = new HttpRequestMessage() };
ta.Request.SetOwinContext( /* mock IOwinContext here */);
```

Sample owin context mock:

```
var owinMock = new Mock<IOwinContext>();
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Authentication.User).Returns(new ClaimsPrincipal());
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Environment).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object> { {"key1", 123} });
var traceMock = new Mock<TextWriter>();
owinMock.Setup(o => o.TraceOutput).Returns(traceMock.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks understood your point. I have already spent time on SetOwinContext() but literally not sure how i can mock it? Any idea

Comment: tried `new Mock<IOwinContext>().Object`? just set up required behavior.

Comment: Thanks, give me few minutes, i check and revert whether it solves my issue or not.

Comment: @ Aleksey L. It mocks OwinContext but gives null for all (Authentication, Environment, Request, Resposnse, TraceOutput). Shouldn't new Mock<IOwinContext>().Object auto populates these objects when mocked?

Comment: No, you should setup all these things (used by controller). See updated answer

Comment: Btw, if you'd use [fakeiteasy](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/) instead of moq it would auto populate these properties with fakes

Comment: Well, i have mocked Request and Response. owinMock.Setup(o => o.Request).Returns(new Mock<OwinRequest>().Object);
            owinMock.Setup(o => o.Response).Returns(new Mock<OwinResponse>().Object); I couldn't find way to mock Environment and TraceOutput.

Comment: Also, i have TestUserManager dervived from UserManager and TestRoleManager dervied from RoleManager class. How i can mock them as well in my above requirement? I come with this so for             var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<TestUser>>();
            var userManager = new TestUserManager(userStore.Object);
 but not sure how i can hook it up with my code. Kindly advise

Comment: The idea is the same - just setup everything you need. Added example for `Environment` and `TraceOutput`. As for `UserManager` you'd better ask a new question and it will be easier to help if you'll show the code were it is used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628372/how-do-i-mock-usermanager-and-rolemanager-for-unit-test