# How do i mock UserManager and RoleManager for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have mocked abstract class to test concrete method of a class as following.

```
var mock = new Mock<BaseTestController>();
mock.CallBase = true;
var ta = mock.Object;

ta.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext { Request = new HttpRequestMessage() };          
var owinMock = new Mock<IOwinContext>();
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Authentication.User).Returns(new ClaimsPrincipal());
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Request).Returns(new Mock<OwinRequest>().Object);
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Response).Returns(new Mock<OwinResponse>().Object);
owinMock.Setup(o => o.Environment).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "key1", 123 } });
var traceMock = new Mock<TextWriter>();
owinMock.Setup(o => o.TraceOutput).Returns(traceMock.Object);

ta.Request.SetOwinContext(owinMock.Object);
var result = await ta.ActivateDeactive("test@user.com", true);
```

Problem:
My abstract class use `Entity Framework 6 and Asp.Net Identity UserManager and RoleManager` as following

```
public TestUserManager UserService
{
    get
    {
        return _userService ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<TestUserManager>();
    }

    private set
    {
        _userService = value;
    }
}

public TestRoleManager RoleService
{
    get
    {
        return _roleService ?? Request.GetOwinContext().Get<TestRoleManager>();
    }

    private set
    {
        _roleService = value;
    }
}
```

How i can mock `TestUserManager and TestRoleManager` in my above mocking code?

I tried the following way but couldn't get the way to hook it up with controllerContext.

```
var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<TestUser>>();
var userManager = new TestUserManager(userStore.Object);
```

> Answer to question asked below by  Aleksey L.

This is how `TestUserManager` derives `UserManaer` and implement.

```
public class TestUserManager : UserManager<TestUser>
{
    public TestUserManager(IUserStore<TestUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
    public static TestUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<TestUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        TestUserManager manager = new TestUserManager(new UserStore<TestUser>(context.Get<AuthContext>()));
        setValidationRules(manager);

        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider == null)
            dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider();
         manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<TestUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")) { TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(expiryTime) };

        return manager;
    }

    public static TestUserManager CreateLocal(AuthContext context)
    {
        TestUserManager manager = new TestUserManager(new UserStore<TestUser>(context));
        setValidationRules(manager);

        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider();
        manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<TestUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        return manager;
    }

    private static void setValidationRules(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<TestUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new ApplicationPasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 30,
            MaximumCharacters = 30,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ActivateDeactive(string studentId, bool active)
{
    IdentityResult result;
    _accountService = new AccountMgtService(UserService, RoleService);
    result = await _accountService.ActiveDeactiveUser(userId, active);

}
```

Comment: Show how controller uses `UserManager`

Comment: Please check my updated question - last part answer to your question.

Comment: I mean the code of controller. Code that calls `UserManager`

Comment: Updated question. Please see at the end of question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you're implementing `TestUserManager` and not just mocking it. Lat's say we have following code in controller:

```
var owinContext = Request.GetOwinContext();
var userManager = owinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var applicationUser = userManager.FindById("testId");
```

You can inject mock user store this way:

```
var owinMock = new Mock<IOwinContext>();

var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
userStoreMock.Setup(s => s.FindByIdAsync("testId")).ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser
{
    Id = "testId",
    Email = "test@email.com"
});
var applicationUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStoreMock.Object);

owinMock.Setup(o => o.Get<ApplicationUserManager>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(applicationUserManager);

ta.Request.SetOwinContext(owinMock.Object);
```

Comment: Excellent. But now i ended with another issue... Why ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(userId); returns null? even though userId exist in database table? Do i need to do something more with mocking?

Comment: Sure, you should set up mock user store. See updated answer. Also you can remove all redundant stuff from the question, so it will be easier to understand for others

Comment: Excellent Aleksey L. Never thought it would be so easy. thanks

Comment: Probably last point, What if i want to read back Id and Email of ApplicationUser? like Var user = obj.Request.GetOwinContext(); I did like this but could not find ApplicationUser object.. All want to check particular property value before and after test call. e.g. isActive

Comment: In example above we're defining the instance of app user which will be returned by id. So you can check this specific instance. Also you'll need to setup another methods of user store like UpdateAsync and maybe others if used.